# USB-C port faulty (MacBook Pro 2019)

Tags: network, usb, thunderbolt, ethernet

> MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
> 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4 AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 8 GB

USB-C > ethernet :

1. Hyper Drive GEN2 12-in-1 USB-C
2. USB C Hub 8 in 1, uni USB-C Hub
3. Anker USB Type-C to Ethernet

I bought a MacBook Pro in July, but I'm getting an issue with the top right USB-C (thunderbolt 3) port.

I initially thought the issue was with the adaptor, which I replaced three times, then got a more expensive USB-C hub, but same issue.

I realised that plugging to the port next to it was solving the issue ...

As you can see, I'm getting 930Mbps +, but when plugging inside the faulty port, this is dropping to 127Mbps,  Example with speed test (same issue with iPef3).
[image: With the top right USB-C Port]
[image: With the USB-C port underneath]

Sometimes I get the full speed with the top right port but most of the time it's dropping drastically.

I swapped the cable, connected to another ETH port, another VLAN, connected the same hub inside another computer (it was working fine).

I first reset PRAM and SMC, same issue, so I erased the partition, installed macOS Big Sur again (11.11 20C69), installed the developer version 11.14 but same issue.

Is there anything else I should know? (I remember reading for example that the power cable should be plugged in the top right port of the MacBook Pro) by the way, the hub I'm using at the moment with ethernet also has PD 100w.

I can arrange to send my Macbook pro for servicing with Apple, but I don't know would that be just a waste of time

Comment: Are you having issues when connecting other devices via this port, such as monitors or external drives? If you start up in safe mode and run hardware diagnostics, does it indicate any issues? If so, it may not be a bad idea to send in your Mac for servicing.

Comment: I booted in diagnostics mode but nothing was detected, I also have a 5K ultra wild monitor plug-in in the same dock and the monitor work just fine. I disconnected the monitor incase that was a bandwidth issue but same thing happen. the only issue I detected was eth, and yet is work just at a lower speed. I don't really have other I/O I can test. assuming the 5K probably using around 22 Gbps, it's weird that I have this issue with ethernet